# Angular 6 Library load in another project at runtime using SystemJS

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, systemjs

I've two `Angular 6` projects, one is `main application` and another is `Angular library` project.

Now I want to load any `library component` at `runtime` without adding reference in `app.module.ts`.

At building of `main application`, I don't know what will be `dynamic library` name so I am using `SystemJS.import('/path/to/library.umd.js')` but this is not working.

exception is `Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'undefined'.`

1. Is there any way to load with `SystemJS`?
2. Any better way as to achieve as `SystemJS` is pretty dead?